# MKMapItem placemark is unavailable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am currently trying to make a searchbar that autopopulates with locations as the user types. I am using a MKLocalSearch to get a MKLocalSearchResponse and it appears to return values I can use. However to get the name, address or coordinates out of the search needs access to the MKPlacemark property in the search response. When I access the placemark I get the error:

'placemark' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

```
var request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText
    //PUT HERE: check if network is on?
    let localSearch: MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (response: MKLocalSearchResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            println("searched")
            for res in response.mapItems {
                self.userSearch.append(res.placemark)
            }
            self.userSearch = response.mapItems.placemark
            self.tableView?.reloadData()
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a workaround to accessing the placemark?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `response.mapItems` array is declared in the API as of type `[AnyObject]!`.

The `for` loop isn't explicitly saying that `res` is of type `MKMapItem` (or that `response.mapItems` is actually `[MKMapItem]`).

So `res` is treated like an instance of `AnyObject` which isn't defined as having a `placemark` property.

This is why you get the compiler error `'placemark' is unavailable...`.

To fix this, cast `res` as an `MKMapItem` and then the `placemark` property will become visible.

Example:

```
for res in response.mapItems {
    if let mi = res as? MKMapItem {
        self.userSearch.append(mi.placemark)
    }
}
```

---

Also, this line after the `for` loop:

```
self.userSearch = response.mapItems.placemark
```

doesn't make sense if `userSearch` is supposed to be an array of placemarks.
The `for` loop is appending placemarks to that array and then this line is setting the array to a single placemark object (in addition, the `mapItems` object doesn't even have a `placemark` property).

This line should most likely be removed.