# Latitude and longitude from MKMapItem in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapitem

Using `MKLocalSearchRequest()` I get an array of `MKMapItem`.

All I need is the latitude and longitude from the item. It seems like it should be easy.

```
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.startWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in
    for item in response.mapItems {

    }
}
```

I have tried `println(item.latitude)`. The console output is `nil`.
Using `item.placemark` to get the lat/longitude doesn't seem to be an option either because `'placemark' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift`

Why is `item.latitude` nil? Why can't I reach into `placemark`?

The console output for `println(item)` is something like this:

```
<MKMapItem: 0x17086a900> {
isCurrentLocation = 0;
name = "Random University";
phoneNumber = "+1000000000";
placemark = "Random University, 400 Address Ave, City, NJ  01010-0000, United States @ <+34.74264816,-84.24657106> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+34.74279563,-84.24621513> radius 514.96', center:<+34.74279563,-84.24621513>, radius:514.96m)";
url = "http://www.shu.edu";
}
```

I can see the latitude and longitude right there! Why can't I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response.mapItems` array is declared in the API as of type `[AnyObject]!`.

The for loop isn't explicitly saying that res is of type `MKMapItem` (or that `response.mapItems` is actually `[MKMapItem]`).

So res is treated like an instance of AnyObject which isn't defined as having a placemark property.

This is why you get the compiler error '`placemark`' is unavailable....

To fix this, cast `res` as an `MKMapItem` and then the placemark property will become visible.

Use this code for getting `placemark`

```
for res in response.mapItems {
    if let mi = res as? MKMapItem {
        self.userSearch.append(mi.placemark)
    }
}
```

Also, this line after the `for` loop:

```
self.userSearch = response.mapItems.placemark
```

For more Info refer [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252319/mkmapitem-placemark-is-unavailable-in-swift) answer.

Answer (score -1):

try this link i hope work for you :

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/searching-map-view-ios8-swift